# 2 gridviews, 2 stored procedures in same page. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want 2 gridview reports in same page.
Gridview1 gets output from stored procedure-1
Gridview2 gets output from stored procedure-2

My code for gridview1 looks like this. I want to know how can I populate gridview2 also in the same page but from different stored procedure.

```
   string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    //con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.CommandText = "OTD";

    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {

        con.Open();
        string sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        DateTime datevalue = (Convert.ToDateTime(sDate.ToString()));

        string dy = datevalue.Day.ToString();
        string mn = datevalue.Month.ToString();
        string yy = datevalue.Year.ToString();
        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", yy);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", mn);
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all in the same .aspx page's code behind

after your first gridview is binded

cmd =   new SqlCommand();

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.CommandText = "My second SP name is herer";

cmd.Connection = con;
```

try
    {

```
    //con.Open(); i am already opened you neverclosed me

    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
     //
```

add any prameters you need
//
        GridView2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

```
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

}
(Catch ex){

}